# C How to capture closing a Terminal

Tags: c, terminal, capture, signals

Any idea on how to capture closing the terminal window that my program is running in?
While I'm at it, any way to capture when the computer is shutting down but the program is still running, or if the user logs off?

Comment: What if the power is cut off immediately? Is it necessary to clean up immediately, or would it be possible to clean up at the next start of the program?

Comment: @Neil: Linux,    @Roland power cut-off can be seen as an exceptional case so I'm not handling that

Answer (score 2):

Try catching SIGTERM. Note that you can not capture SIGKILL which might be what happens during shutdown after a certain amount of time. I found this [really nice post](http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/) that explains some differences too.

*[update] Longshot here but what about testing if std-in/out is still open and good? When the terminal dies those file descriptors should be scrapped. Disclaimer, this is a guess at best.*

Comment: Like I said, I tried testing capturing all the various signals. SIGTERM I geuss will work for Shutdown, haven't tested yet, but it definately does not work for closing terminal... any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your program isn't actually being killed when the console does. You should be able to verify that, but either way try testing stdin/stdout to see if they are still "live". That's the best I got.

Answer (score 2):

If on Unix/Linux: Did you have a look at SIGTERM? This is at least the one sent to you during shutdown.

Comment: SIGTERM will probably work for shut-down, I haven't tested... but it most definately does not work for closing a terminal, which to me is more important right now... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

<del>You could try the atexit() function ?</del> (see comments)

Or look at this post here: [Signals received by bash when terminal is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546223/signals-received-by-bash-when-terminal-is-closed)

Comment: atexit is only for normal program termination which is defined as "either by a call to exit() or a return from main()"

Answer (score 1):

From my tests... the signal that my program is receiving when closing terminal is 1 or SIGHUP

Comment: The answers that say SIGTERM are wrong. SIGHUP is the signal sent when the terminal is closed.