# How to record all terminal sessions and properly exit after closed window

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, zsh

I am trying to setup my environment so that all opened terminal sessions are automatically recorded by [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/), to be able to easily replay anything from my history.

I use `zsh` shell and I run this in `.zshrc`:

```
if [ "$ASCIINEMA_REC" != "1" ]; then
    local out="rec.json"
    local loc="$HOME/.asciinema"

    if [ -d "${loc}" ]; then
        out="${loc}`pwd`/rec_`date +'%Y-%b-%d_%H-%M-%S'`_pts-`basename $TTY`.json"
        mkdir -p "`dirname ${out}`"
    fi

    asciinema rec -q -w 1 ${out}; 
fi
```

However the problem is when I close the terminal window (using **X**). The output is not properly closed and ends up being empty. Also the initialization takes longer now since it is initializing zsh shell two times.

Comment: This is just a short update because it's not official yet: asciinema will have a new fileformat and does save in realtime instead at the end of the session. https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/pull/236

Answer (score 1):

I would try to `trap` `SIGHUP` and `EXIT` so that you can process a cleanup command when your terminal is closed.

```
trap 'command' SIGHUP EXIT
```

So, in your case, probably making sure that you close the pseudo-terminal ran by `asciinema` correctly.

Maybe:

```
trap 'exit 0;' SIGHUP EXIT # Should exit the current terminal session, hopefully the asciinema one!
```

Reference: [Which signals are sent when closing a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546223/signals-received-by-bash-when-terminal-is-closed)